# c# is it possible to create extension method for string keyword

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I created an extension method for generating string from `System.Guid` like this.

```
public static class Fnk
{

    public static string Guid(bool dash = true)
    {
        return dash ? System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    }
}
```

I am using it like `Fnk.Guid()`. I wonder that, is it possible to call it like `string.Guid()`? If yes, how?

Comment: `this sting variableName` must be the first argument. In your code you just return a guid value based on condition

Comment: An extension-method has a `this`-kewyord for the param. Your code is no extension-method.

Comment: Do you want to parse string to guid? what will the string.Guid() method do?

Comment: Also, Guid already has an option for generating a dash-less string. `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what's the point of this. [`Guid` has an overload of `ToString` that takes in a string as a format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Guid_ToString_System_String_) - use `"N"` to remove the dashes.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who warned me. I fixed the dash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to call it like `string.Guid()`

No. Extension methods allow static methods to be called *as if they're instance methods*. You're trying to write a static method and allow it to be called *as if it's a static method on an unrelated type*.

That isn't supported - at least not as of C# 8.

Writing genuine extension methods targeting `string` is entirely feasible. For example:

```cs
public static class PointlessExtensions
{
    public static HasEvenLength(this string text) => (text.Length & 1) == 0;
}
```

Called as:

```cs
bool result1 = "odd".HasEvenLength(); // False
bool result2 = "even".HasEvenLength(); // True
```

Comment: Small addition: if a class derives another having  static member, you´ll be able to call that static member via the derived class as well.

Comment: "PointlessExtensions". I think I'm going to use that name.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much for your interest and support.